# My android app is working on DHU but not seen on Android auto car screen

Tags: android, android-auto

I just started to develop apps for cars a month ago and still a lot of black spots in my mind. I have developed an android app for navigation that can be used in Android car mirroring. When I test my app on DHU everything works perfect but I tried to test my app on a real car screen connected to android phone over bluetooth and even USB and my app is not shown on the car screen launcher.

In my mobile side of the app I use a CarConnection to see when phone is connected to car so that I can use car screen and that connection observer triggers when I open the app on phone while connected to car. But when I check the car screen launcher still not see my app there.

I have checked my Android auto Customize Launcher on my phone and the app was not there not even on the hidden Apps Section, like it shows on my DHU.

I have tried enable/disable developer options.

I have `CarService` declared on Manifest like so:

```
<service android:name="com.package.name.MyAutoService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService"/>
                <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.car.app.action.NAVIGATE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="geo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I mention that on mobile I have installed a debug apk.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong or what should I do? I really need to make sure how this app would look on a real screen.

Answer (score 2):

Have you turned on the "Unknown sources" setting in the [Android Auto app's developer settings](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#developer-mode)?

If not, apps must be installed from a trusted source to be runnable on a real car's head unit. The easiest way to distribute your app from a trusted source would be to use Play's [Internal App Sharing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/) or an [Internal Test Track](https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing/). See [Test in real vehicles](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#real-vehicles) for more details.

Comment: However enabling the unknown sources only work for media or messaging apps. For other kinds of apps must be installed from a trusted source to be runnable on a real car's head unit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue. It turned out to be related to minifyEnabled / proguard.

If you have "minifyEnabled true" in your gradle, try setting it to false and see if that resolves the issue. If it does, you will need to edit your proguard rules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).